# What's the difference between 'aggregator' and 'bond' in Linux bonding?

Tags: linux

Recently, I'm view the bonding code in Linux. But I just failed to understand some terms:bond, aggregator, slave and port. I think 'bond' and 'aggregator' are the same concept, and one bond has many slaves, when a port has been added to one bond, then it's called slave. While I saw the comment about function __get_next_agg: get the next aggregator in the bond. It seems that one bond could has many aggregators...Who can explain these terms, thanks!

Comment: I think you should read GNU/Linux Bonding driver documentation, especially the section on `mode` parameter listing all possible uses of bonding. BTW, one of them is "IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation (802.3ad)"

Comment: I have read both 'bonding.txt' and 'IEEE 802.3ad', so I understand. But the code just confuse me.